# Axios with node.js - ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm firing a `GET` request from a simply configured `axios` instance:

```
var Axios = axios.create({
        baseURL: myBaseUrl,
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    });

Axios.get(url)
```

And been getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at dispatchXhrRequest (C:\...\node_modules\axios\dist\axios.js:804:24)
    at xhrAdapter (C:\...\node_modules\axios\dist\axios.js:796:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3
```

To my understanding (and according to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)), axios should work on both web browsers and node.js.

What am i missing?

Versions:

```
node - 6.2.1
axios - 0.13.1
```

Comment: How do you require axios in node? It looks like you are requiring a browser-side file and this line `node_modules\axios\dist\axios.js` confirms it. It should be `node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js`

Comment: @Molda that's it! thanks, post it as an answer and i'll accept.

Comment: Cool, will do. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are requiring a browser-side file and this line `node_modules\axios\dist\axios.js` confirms it.

It should be `node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js`

**Update:**

for **node.js** use

```
var axios = require('axios');
```

and for **browser** simply add a script tag and `axios` object should be globally available

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

or link your local *axios.min.js* file for example

```
<script src="/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```